# How to downgrade from Django 1.7 to Django 1.6

Tags: python, django, django-1.6, django-1.7

I started a new project a few months back using Django 1.7. The company has decided to settle on using Django 1.6 for all projects.

Is there a nice way to downgrade from Django 1.7 to 1.6?

Are migrations the only thing I have to worry about? Are the changes between the two versions large enough that I need to rewrite the app? I was hoping to just change the version in the `requirements.txt` and then install `south` and create new database migrations.

Comment: Oh, that's interesting. Is your company going to use this version forever?

Comment: The only major change I can recall being introduced in 1.7 is the database migrations functionality (which you can still use by using south). Scan the 1.6-1.7 changelog and see if your app uses anything new. If it doesn't, it should be as simple as installing 1.6 instead of 1.7.

Comment: Your company should bear in mind that the Django project does *not* intend to support 1.6 on a long-term basis, so security fixes will not be backported once 1.8 is released. 1.4 was the last LTS release, and 1.8 will be the next.

Comment: @DanielRoseman you're suggesting that new Django projects should always use the latest version? I checked out Mozilla and they seem to be stuck on 1.6

Comment: No, not suggesting that at all, just that you should bear in mind the consequences of such a decision, especially considering 1.6 is nearing end-of-life.

Comment: you should really tell your company's IT about `virtualenv`.

Comment: type `pip install Django==1.6` on your terminal

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Use:

```
sudo pip install Django==1.6.10
```

Comment: Remove all the files in migration folders, and `makemigration` again.

Answer (score 2):

You should check the [Django release notes for 1.7](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/releases/1.7/).
Just doing what you propose should be enough, but check if you are using things that changed in that log. That is project specific.

Answer (score 2):

For Windows:

```
pip install -U Django==required version
```

You will have to make changes to the original suite sub-folder.

Answer (score 0):

pip install Django==1.6 in CMD